# Ajax between two PHP scripts

Tags: php, ajax, json, http

I'm tring to perform an AJAX request between 2 PHP scripts, one of them just returns (echoes) some data in the form of a json string:

```
[{'foo':'bar'}]
```

And the other one just makes a simple http request to it:

```
$c = new http\Client;
$r = new http\Client\Request('GET', 'http://example.com/script.php');
$c->enqueue($r,
    function(http\Client\Response $r) {
            // Do something with the Json here.
            return true;
    })->send();
```

But I just can't figure out how to get that Json string from the `Response` object. PECL's [documentation](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Client) doesn't help at all:

```
<?php

$request = new http\Client\Request("GET",
    "http://example.com",
    ["User-Agent"=>"My Client/0.1"]
);
$request->setOptions(["timeout"=>1]);

$client = new http\Client;
$client->enqueue($request)->send();

// pop the last retrieved response
$response = $client->getResponse();
printf("%s returned '%s' (%d)\n",
    $response->getTransferInfo("effective_url"),
    $response->getInfo(),
    $response->getResponseCode()
);
?>
```

This just yields:

> http://example.com/ returned 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' (200)

But nothing more. How can I do this?

**Update:**

This is a dump of the `Response` object using `var_dump`.

```
object(http\Client\Response)[6]
  protected 'type' => int 2
  protected 'body' => 
    object(http\Message\Body)[5]
  protected 'requestMethod' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'requestUrl' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'responseStatus' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  protected 'responseCode' => int 200
  protected 'httpVersion' => string '1.1' (length=3)
  protected 'headers' => 
    array (size=7)
      'Server' => string 'nginx/1.4.7' (length=11)
      'Date' => string 'Sat, 20 Dec 2014 23:20:07 GMT' (length=29)
      'Content-Type' => string 'text/html' (length=9)
      'Connection' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
      'X-Powered-By' => string 'PHP/5.5.19' (length=10)
      'X-Original-Transfer-Encoding' => string 'chunked' (length=7)
      'Content-Length' => int 1695
  protected 'parentMessage' => 
    object(http\Client\Request)[3]
      protected 'type' => int 1
      protected 'body' => 
        object(http\Message\Body)[8]
      protected 'requestMethod' => string 'GET' (length=3)
      protected 'requestUrl' => string 'http://localhost/battleturnrest/work.GetTop50.php' (length=49)
      protected 'responseStatus' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'responseCode' => int 0
      protected 'httpVersion' => string '1.1' (length=3)
      protected 'headers' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'parentMessage' => null
      protected 'options' => null
  protected 'transferInfo' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'effective_url' => string 'http://localhost/battleturnrest/work.GetTop50.php' (length=49)
      public 'response_code' => int 200
      public 'total_time' => float 0.01084
      public 'namelookup_time' => float 0.000913
      public 'connect_time' => float 0.001345
      public 'pretransfer_time' => float 0.002432
      public 'size_upload' => float 0
      public 'size_download' => float 1695
      public 'speed_download' => float 156365
      public 'speed_upload' => float 0
      public 'header_size' => int 180
      public 'request_size' => int 135
      public 'ssl_verifyresult' => int 0
      public 'filetime' => int -1
      public 'content_length_download' => float -1
      public 'content_length_upload' => float 0
      public 'starttransfer_time' => float 0.010685
      public 'content_type' => string 'text/html' (length=9)
      public 'redirect_time' => float 0
      public 'redirect_count' => int 0
      public 'connect_code' => int 0
      public 'httpauth_avail' => int 0
      public 'proxyauth_avail' => int 0
      public 'os_errno' => int 111
      public 'num_connects' => int 1
      public 'ssl_engines' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'cookies' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'primary_ip' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
      public 'appconnect_time' => float 0
      public 'condition_unmet' => int 0
      public 'primary_port' => int 80
      public 'local_ip' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
      public 'local_port' => int 45915
      public 'curlcode' => int 0
      public 'error' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: is there a `$response->getBody()` function or something similar?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't contain anything related to the actual response I'm expecting, I may update the question to append a dump of the response object.

Comment: Personally, I don't get my head worked up with ajax when I can use simplified libraries like jQuery.... $.load would've solved your problem easily.

Comment: Can you print the contents of the body? (`http\Message\Body`)

Comment: I wouldn't say this is an `ajax` call, it's a server to server request. No clients and javascript involved

Comment: @DLastCodeBender I don't plan to implement js' ajax (I know it'd have been easier) but it surprises me that such a (supposedly) powerful tool can't deliver the simplest functionality one may expect.

Comment: This all seems overkill for what you're trying to achieve. Won't `$response=file_get_contents('http://example.com/script.php');` do what you need?

Comment: @HoboSapiens I was looking for *ways to perform an http request* and came upon this, I didn't know a simple `get_contents` would do the trick.

Comment: The Ajax technology itself is about threads. Different instances of `XMLHttpRequest` work simultaneously and produce unsynchronized callback functions calls. Your PHP have no threads. It is just about `file_get_contents()` call and nothing more.

Comment: It is looks like you trying to rewrite web server over Apache web server, are you?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to get the output of a script from another script, all on the server side; `file_get_contents` works, but not for a script that needs params, maybe I need to convert some chars to URL entities, and as for the title, it's because the old one wasn't catching enough attention (it was too technical), I know AJAX by definition hast to do with javascript (client-side) and not a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the same call-request scenario. The `main.php` calls `answer.php`, and it answers with json.

answer.php

```
<?php
    // the json header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // parameter "value" from URL http://.../answer.php?value=bar
    $value = $_REQUEST["value"];
    // returns exactly [{'foo':'bar'}]
    echo(json_encode(array(array("foo" => $value))));
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
    ...
    $bar = "bar";
    $url = "http://.../answer.php?value=" . $bar;
    $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    ...
>
```

The most important thing is main.php executes line by line and you can not send two or more calls to the `answer.php` in the same moment.

But if:

main.php

```
<?php 
// the crucial difference: asynchronous calls to the answer.php 
class Ask_For_Value extends Thread {

    public function __construct($value, $func){
        $this->val = $value;
        $this->func = $func;    
    }

    function start(){
        $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://.../answer.php?value=" . $this->val));
        call_user_func($this->func, $arr);
        return(0);// boolean "OK"
    }
}

// function to process the result
function do_some_thihg_with_the_result(&$array){...}

// prepare the threads
$call1 = new Ask_For_Value("bar_1", "do_some_thihg_with_the_result");
$call2 = new Ask_For_Value("bar_2", "do_some_thihg_with_the_result");
$call3 = new Ask_For_Value("bar_3", "do_some_thihg_with_the_result");

// start the threads
$call1->start();
$call2->start();
$call3->start();

// there is nothing happens, because the threads
// will continue execution asynchronous and 
// independent in the "function do_some_thihg_with_the_result()" 

?>
```